# Express server doesn't respond and crashes while testing it through Postman

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, postman, bcrypt

I am trying to test this using POSTMAN but when I do the post request for /register /login the server is getting crashed and getting the following error:

```
Could not get any response
    There was an error connecting to localhost:3000/api/user/current.
    Why this might have happened:
    The server couldn't send a response:
    Ensure that the backend is working properly
    Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
    Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
    Proxy configured incorrectly
    Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
    Request timeout:
    Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

The error that I am getting on my node terminal is:

```
if(err) throw err;
                            ^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (/Volumes/-Xizt's Storage/project/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (/Volumes/-Xizt's Storage/project/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:220:13)
    at bcrypt.genSalt (/Volumes/-Xizt's Storage/project/route/api/user.js:29:24)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Volumes/-Xizt's Storage/project/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:153:21)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

passport.js

```
const jwtStrategy=require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt=require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const User=mongoose.model('User');
const key=require('../config/key');

const options={};
options.jwtFromRequest=ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
options.secretOrKey=key.secretOrKey;

module.exports=passport=>{
    passport.use(new jwtStrategy(options,(jwt_checking, done)=>{
        console.log(jwt_checking);
        User.findById(jwt_checking.id).then(user=>{
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }
            return done(null,false);
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }))
}
```

This is the main file of the application. index.js

```
const express= require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const user=require('./route/api/user');
const userprofile=require('./route/api/userprofile');
const passport=require('passport');
const key=require('./config/key');


const app=express();
//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//database confid into variable using variable name that I used in key.js of config folder
const database=require('./config/key').mongoURI;

//connecting to mongodb
//.then will print connected if successful
//catch will print error if not
mongoose.connect(database).then(()=>console.log("connected")).catch(err=>console.log(err));

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

//passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//gave port number 3000 input to run
//using route to check the output of user.js and userprofile.sj
app.use('/api/user',user);
app.use('/api/userprofile',userprofile);
//will run at 3000 port on localhost
const port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

//it will print this in the terminal after npm start or npm run server 
//this will print the consr port in conlsole
app.listen(port,()=> console.log('port is:: ${port}'));
```

user.js

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const user=require('../../model/User');
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
const key=require('../../config/key');
const passport=require('passport');


router.get('/demo',(req,res)=>res.json({output:"user"}));

//creating route for regsiteration
//using postman it will get this 
router.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    //find if email exists or not.
    user.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(user=>{
        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({email:"email is already registered"});
        }
        else{
            //else will creaete new user
            const newUser=new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                email:req.body.email,
                password:req.body.password
            })

            //generate salt and hash pass with salt
            bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt)=>{
                //hashing password
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err,hash)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    //after setting hash password will save it
                    newUser.password=hash;
                    newUser.save()
                    //then will return through json
                    .then(user=>res.json(user))

                })
            })
        }
    })
});

//returning jason web token
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    const email=req.body.email;
    const password=req.body.password;
    //will find user by email
    //will check if email and pass is present in mlab db
    User.findOne({email}).then(user=>{
        if(!user){
            return res.status(404).json({email:"user doesnt exist"});
    }
    //
            bcrypt.compare(password,user.password).then(isMatch=>{
                if(isMatch){
                    //user matched
                    //checking will check the details of user
                    const checking={id: user.id,name:user.name}
                    //
                    jwt.sign(checking,key.key1,(err,token)=>{
                        res.json({
                            access:true,
                            token:token
                        })
                    });

            }
                    else{
                    return res.status(400).json({password:"password incorrect"});
        }

            })

    })
})

router.get(
    '/current',
    passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), 
    (req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        id:req.user.id,
        name:req.user.name,
        email:req.user.email


})
    }
)


module.exports=router;
```

I am trying to test the /login and /register API for the web application but it is getting crashed and doesn't connect after I try to use POSTMAN.

Comment: please check in `bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err,hash)=>{` if `newUser.password` is coming correctly

Comment: Very good chance the `req.body.password` is not coming to the endpoint

Comment: I am not able to check that as the server isn't running.